# How to check which list an element is contained in

Tags: python, python-3.x

*DISCLAIMER: I am not asking how to check if an element is contained within a list. I am asking how to check which list an element is contained in.*

Consider this code:

```
x = ["i", "hello", "great"]
y = ["what", "food"]
chosen = input("Input a word: ")
#what comes next?
```

I want to print the name of the list that variable `chosen` is a part of (the program should print `x`, `y`, or just nothing at all)

How would I determine which list the inputted word is a part of?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
x = ["i", "hello", "great"]
y = ["what", "food"]
chosen = input("Input a word: ")
if chosen in x:print("x")
if chosen in y:print("y")
elif chosen not in x:print("Not Found!")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a data structure designed for quick lookup. Presumably, none of your lists will contain conflicting elements. In that case, the *elements* are perfect candidates for dictionary keys. This calls for the relatively arcane method [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
x = [...]
y = [...]

mapping = {}
mapping.update(dict.fromkeys(x, 'x'))
mapping.update(dict.fromkeys(y, 'y'))
```

Now you have a dictionary that will immediately tell you where a word belongs:

```
word = input().casefold()
print(mapping.get(word, 'Not Found!'))
```

I'd probably stick this into a class to manage the dictionary, lists and lookup. You could register a list under any name that way:

```
class WordLists(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super ().__init__()

    def register_list(name, data):
        self.update(dict.fromkeys(data, name))

    def __getitem__(self, word):
        return super().get(word.casefold(), 'Not Found')

wl = WordList()
wl.register('x', x)
wl.register('y', y)
print(wl[input()])
```

Part of what you need to remember is that python variables can be bound to any number of names. That's why I suggest explicitly stating what name you want to return for each list. It doesn't have to be related to the name of the variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = ((x, "x"), (y, "y")) 

[print(lst_name) for lst, lst_name in pairs if chosen in lst]
```

The first statement constructs the tuple of pairs of type `(list, list_name)`, the second is the list comprehension which as a *side effect* prints the name(s) of the appropriate list(s).